# How to extract floating point second from POSIXct object in R?

Tags: r

I am working on a project that requires getting the exact second from a POSIXct object. For example, if printing out a POSIXct object named `tm` :

```
> tm
[1]  "2017-07-10 09:03:32.26876 BRT"
> class(tm)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

If I run:

```
> format(tm, "%S")
[1] "32"
```

which only prints out the decimal, instead I want "32.26876", how do I do that? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?strftime` the following is noted:

> Specific to R is `%OSn`, which for output gives the seconds
>     truncated to `0 <= n <= 6` decimal places (and if `%OS` is not
>     followed by a digit, it uses the setting of
>     `getOption("digits.secs")`, or if that is unset, `n = 0`).

Hence we can recover up to 6 decimal places, although there seems to be some change in this information:

```
> tm <- as.POSIXct("2017-07-10 09:03:32.26876", tz = "BRT")
> tm
[1] "2017-07-10 09:03:32.268 BRT"
> format(tm, "%OS5")
[1] "32.26875"
> format(tm, "%OS6")
[1] "32.268759"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `%OS` parameter to extract fractional seconds:

```
tm <- as.POSIXct("2017-07-10 09:03:32.26876 BRT", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
class(tm)
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

# set the second digits option
options(digits.secs=5)

# `strftime` or `format`:

strftime(tm, "%OS")
#[1] "32.26875"

format(tm, "%OS")
#[1] "32.26875"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you convert it to a POSIXlt, this is easy.

```
tm = as.POSIXct("2017-07-10 09:03:32.26876 BRT")
as.POSIXlt(tm)$sec
[1] 32.26876
```